# Low CPU utilization in Spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I'm running a Spark job in local mode on a 8 core machine.  It has a local SSD and 64GB of RAM. HDFS is being run in pseudo distributed mode on the same machine.  When running the below job, I can't get CPU utilization to get past maxing out a single core.  RAM usage stays under 10GB.  The loopback interface maxes out around 333MB/s.  Disk IO is typically under 30MB/s either way.  How can I write this to make better use of my hardware resources?

```
object FilterProperty {
    def main(args:Array[String]) {
        val conf = new SparkConf()
            .setAppName("Filter Claims Data for Property")
            .setMaster("local")
            .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
            .set("spark.cores.max", "16")
        conf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[JsObject]))
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
        val filtered = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/user/kevin/intermediate/claims.json", 48)
            .filter(s => s != "")
            .map(s => Json.parse(s).as[JsObject])
            .filter(Util.property_filter)
        filtered.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/user/kevin/intermediate/property_claims.json" + fn)
        sc.stop()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change this line of code

```
.setMaster("local")
```

to

```
.setMaster("local[*]")
```

which means using as many threads as cores on your machine. Or you can set a number instead of `*` which means use that number of threads.

Comment: Awesome, that gets me to ~90% total utilization.  Thanks.